# SQL to UPDATE all records except ones that belong to a specific table

Tags: mysql, sql

For my tables `users` and `assigned_roles` I want to set `users.confirmed = 0` except where `users` belongs to `assigned_roles`.

**assigned_roles table**
    ID| USER_ID| ROLES

**SQL**

```
UPDATE users, assigned_roles
SET users.confirmed=0
WHERE users.id != assigned_roles.user_id
```

I know my last line is wrong. What is the correct way to do the query to get it to run on all users except the ones with assigned roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. Just need a subquery in that WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE users
SET confirmed=0
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM assigned_roles);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with join . . . but left join:

```
UPDATE users u LEFT JOIN
       assigned_roles ar
       ON u.id = ar.user_id
    SET u.confirmed = 0
    WHERE ar.user_id IS NULL;
```

`LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS` are better for this query because of the way they handle `NULL` values of `assigned_roles.user_id`.